# Correct way to handle mulitple http Request async with error handling

Tags: c#, rest, http, async-await

The solution works, but is there a better way to handle multiple requests like this with the errorhandling.

The below code describes what i want to do, and absolutely works. But I'm sure there is a better way to go about the issue?
I've tried other options as well but it fails as some of the requests will return a 404.

```
public async Task<List<Bruker>> TryGetContactsByContactIds(List<AZContact> contacts)
{
    var tasks = contacts.Select(c => TryGetContactAsync(c.Email)).Where(c => c.Result != null);

    try
    {
        var tasksresult = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        return tasksresult.ToList();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        _logger.Error("unable to fetch all", e);
    }


    return new List<Bruker>();
}

public async Task<Bruker> TryGetContactAsync(string userId)
{
    try
    {
        var user = await _brukereClient.GetAsync(userId);
        return user;
    }
    catch (SwaggerException e)
    {
        if (e.StatusCode == 404)
        {
            _logger.Info($"user with Id {userId} does not exist");
        }
        else
        {
            _logger.Error("Unable to fetch user", e);
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are probably dealing with a feature/limitation of `await`, that throws only one of the aggregated exceptions of the awaited task (the `WhenAll` task in this case). You must enumerate all the tasks to handle each individual exception.

```
try
{
    var tasksresult = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    return tasksresult.ToList();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    foreach (var task in tasks)
    {
        if (task.IsFaulted)
        {
            var taskException = task.Exception.InnerException;
            // ^^ Assuming that each task cannot have more than one exception inside its AggregateException.
            if (taskException is SwaggerException swaggerException)
            {
                if (swaggerException.StatusCode == 404)
                {
                    _logger.Info($"user with Id {userId} does not exist");
                }
                else
                {
                    _logger.Error("Unable to fetch user", swaggerException);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                _logger.Error("An unexpected task error occurred", taskException);
            }
        }
    }
    if (!tasks.Any(t => t.IsFaulted))
    {
        _logger.Error("A non task-related error occurred", e);
    }
}
```